# Bokeh uncheck checkbox

Tags: bokeh

For now, I am trying to simply uncheck a Bokeh checkbox using a custom button.

But I'm getting unexpected results: The boxes are not being created in the checked state and the button does not clear the checkboxes.

Is this because I'm misunderstanding the `active` attribute?

```
from bokeh.models.widgets import CheckboxGroup, Button
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.plotting import show

checkbox_group_1 = CheckboxGroup(labels=["Group 1 Button"], active=[1])
checkbox_group_2 = CheckboxGroup(labels=["Group 2 Button A", "Group 2 Button B"], active=[1,1])
checkbox_group_3 = CheckboxGroup(labels=["Group 3 Button A", "Group 3 Button B"], active=[1,1])


button = Button(label="Foo", button_type="success")

def buttonclick():
    checkbox_group_1.active = [0]
    checkbox_group_2.active = [0,0]
    checkbox_group_3.active = [0,0]

button.on_click(buttonclick)


layout=column(checkbox_group_1,checkbox_group_2,checkbox_group_3, button)
curdoc().add_root(layout)


!powershell -command {'bokeh serve --show Buttoninteraction.ipynb'}
#I'm working within Jupyter notebook.
```

Ideally, I'd like to have boxes get unchecked when one from another group is checked. 
Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `active` attribute is a list that specifies the index of the selected items. So to unselect them all simply use `checkbox_group.active = []`

```
from bokeh.models.widgets import CheckboxGroup, Button
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.plotting import show

checkbox_group_1 = CheckboxGroup(labels = ["Group 1 Button"], active = [0])
checkbox_group_2 = CheckboxGroup(labels = ["Group 2 Button A", "Group 2 Button B"], active = [1])
checkbox_group_3 = CheckboxGroup(labels = ["Group 3 Button A", "Group 3 Button B"], active = [1])

button = Button(label = "Foo", button_type = "success")

def buttonclick():
    checkbox_group_1.active = []
    checkbox_group_2.active = []
    checkbox_group_3.active = []

button.on_click(buttonclick)

layout = column(checkbox_group_1, checkbox_group_2, checkbox_group_3, button)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

Example for `active` value for checkbox_group_2:

```
value      selected
[0]        first 
[1]        second
[0, 1]     both
[]         None
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!